# WebRTC on apple devices does not work, even though it does on web and android

Tags: ios, flutter, web, webrtc

I'm making an web app with flutter_webrtc that is supposed to make videocalls cross-platform.
It works from Windows - Linux - Android, though, when I try it on a MacBook or an Iphone, the Apple user can't hear or see the other one, even though the other one can see him.
Also no console errors even come up, it's like its a error that does not exist

I based my code on this repo: https://github.com/md-weber/webrtc_tutorial

I tried basically the same thing I tried on all the other OSes, created a room, made an offer, sent it then joined. And while the communication did work, the apple user can't hear or see the other.

Comment: Same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Same issue here LoL. Any solution at the moment?